# Who took care of Melody during her "childhood" in Leadworth?

Tags: doctor-who

I am attempting to get info on how Melody got to Leadworth and who her "stand in" parents were, if any existed. (Amy and Rory would not count in the eyes of society). Since she regenerated as a toddler and then went to school with Rory and Amy, my question is who drove her to school in the mornings? An 8-year-old or toddler without any parents is what you might call neglect.

Day-to-day, who took care of her in Leadworth? At the very least she would need a guardian or chauffeur. I know there's a Krampus comic out there but I  only have the general plot.

Comment: Wasn't Amy about that age (8), living alone,when she first met Eleven?  Admittedly that was because her parents had been lost in "the crack", but she *was* still living alone at a similar age -- and no one in town seemed to do anything, or even care.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - shhhhh... this is _Doctor Who_, we can't go around expecting plot consistency from episode to episode!

Comment: @zeiss ikon Actually there is an explanation for Amy being alone that night. The crack.ate her parents and her Aunt was.out at the time. The nature  of the crack made her and others accept that. It's actually something that the Doctor POINTS OUT as something out of the ordinary.

Comment: And we know from the Apple that her mom at least had been eaten that very night. Because the apple with the face was carved by her mom her mom was gone and the Doctor shows it as proof of time travel because it hadn't  yet even browned. The person who drove Amy to school in that initial reality was actually her parents. And after they were eaten, her Aunt.

Comment: @Zeis Ikon Given that her mom at least must've disappeared just moments before her prayer to Santa, that hardly counts as an eight - year - old living alone. (See comment on apple carving above).

Comment: "Last time I did this, I ended up a toddler **in the middle of New York**" - she was probably older than a toddler by the time she got to Leadworth (though I suppose that doesn't change the question much)

Comment: Which raises the question: How did she get to Leadworth from NYC?

Comment: @tilley31 I have that question as well but was more interested in getting this one answered. More likely since I know there's at least one comic out there coving the childhood in Lead worth years.

Comment: @tilley31: Do we know how old she is by the time she regenerates into Mels (or even, do we know how many regenerations have happened since then?) River could be hundreds of years old by the time she regenerates in New York. Which makes sense, given Mel's confident attitude and skilled behavior (which carries over to River). She's likely not as young as she looks.

Comment: In the story Imaginary Enemies, she doesn't have a parent at her nativity play.

Comment: @tilley31 Considering the time-displaced Amy and Rory are still alive in New York in the late 60s, early 70s, and probably knowing River's full history by that point, they might just help toddler-Mels themselves. (At leats that's always been my head canon, and would put a nice bookend around their relationship with her)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, Melody "regenerated as a toddler". She wasn't actually a true toddler when Amy and Rory went to school with her. Depending on her *actual age* (as opposed to her *physical age*) she probably didn't need  anyone to "take care" of her.

We don't actually know how many regenerations Melody/Riversong had. When we see Melody's first form begin to regenerate she is slightly older than what you would call a "toddler". She also appears to be dying of neglect, as she appears hungry and sick. This would suggest that at this point in her life she was *not* being cared for. We don't know for certain that she regenerated into the form of "Mels" at this time, but if she did then she immediately went from a neglected and scared child to a neglected and scared toddler. By the time we see "Mels", she has been fully indoctrinated and trained for her purpose of killing The Doctor.

Although we can only guess (at this point) whether or not she had any generations inbetween these two, I find it **unlikely** that the Silence went from "neglecting" her one moment to caring for her and training her immediately following her first regenration. Also, why would a helpless child regenerate into a toddler? It has been established that The Doctor's own regenerations are "guided" by his subconscious out of necessity (the 12th Doctor apparently took the form of an older man to (i) reestablish his relationship with Clara - "I'm not your boyfriend", and (ii) remind him not to leave anyone behind by taking the face of someone he had once saved) Becoming a toddler would not make the starving and sick Melody's plight any better. I would suggest that it is far more likely that regeneration into a toddler was something that happened later out of the necessity to infiltrate Amy and Rory's childhood. She could have had another regeneration inbetween and then recruited back into The Church of the Silence some time after that. Additionally I find it unlikely that Mels' training to kill The Doctor came *after* she had established a *real* childhood friendship with Amy and Rory because the Silence would have had to "undo" all that conditioning and essentially turn a good child with real friends into a ruthless killer. It seems far more likely that she had already been conditioned by The Silence and was undercover from the moment she met Amy.

Given all of the above I would say it is certain Mels didn't *actually* need "looking after" - that only leaves the question of *how she didn't attract any attention being taken to/from school without a real parent or guardian*. Well, following the same reasoning that she must have been undercover as Amy's childhood friend from the very beginning, she must have been under the control/influence of The Silence the whole time. Therefore there would have been no "real" parent or guardian to fool/kill off. She *could* have had someone else from The Church of the Silence acting as a "stooge" parent. Or, if that is too boring and predictable an answer, she could also have been under the care of "a Silent" and nobody would have questioned it because *nobody would have remembered seeing it*.

Answer (score 2):

It's not explicitly explained/shown, but we must assume that it is a series of agents of The Church of the Silence.

We saw in Day of the Moon that the orphanage where Melody was kept/held/raised in her younger years was infested by The Silence. The administrator of the facility seemed very confused, only sure of the importance of keeping his charge safe.

Since we never see, or hear any mention of, Melody's guardians, it is reasonable to surmise that they are never seen by anyone, and perhaps by using something akin to a Perception Filter like in Amy's house for the missing room (or a Somebody Else's Problem Field like in Hitchhiker's) , nobody "notices" that this is a problem.

For all the times we see Melody at the principal's office, the only person waiting for her is Amy. There's any possibility that each time she enters the office, a Silence enters with her, who tell the principal that all is well.

Whimsically, one could wonder if there's robot parents that answer the door, like on Invader Zim...

Comment: Yes, but, I had thought that when she lived in Leadworth, it was after she escaped them, or at least when they had given her freedom enough to be on her own.

Comment: Considering she was still set to kill The Doctor, odds are she was still under their control/training at the time, which leads to the idea that she was still being cared for by them.